# Predicting purchase order?

Tags: time-series, forecast, survival-analysis

What is the best option or rather options to predict how much order a customer will place in the future, say next 3 months on a monthly basis. Also will a customer place an order.

I used ARIMA to predict the future order but the MAPE is quite high. Basically what i have done is predict the probability of a customer placing an order using survival analysis and then multiplied that with the predicted order quantity.

Does that make sense or is there something fundamentally wrong with the approach?

Comment: A common way to do it is market basket analysis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_analysis